# Replacement rule to set `Floor[Mod[H, p1*p2...pm]/(p1*p2...pm)]` to zero where the length of the product p1*p2...pm will vary

Tags: replacement

For example I have tried:

`Floor[Mod[H, p1*p2*p3]/(p1*p2*p3)]/.{Floor[Mod[H, x_]/(x_)]->0}`

and

`Floor[Mod[H, p1*p2*p3]/(p1*p2*p3)]/.{Floor[Mod[H, x__]/(x__)]->0}`

but they not does work except for the case where the product is just p1.  The number of elements in these products will vary from p1 to p1*p2*...*pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind is that `/` is translated into `Times` and `Power`, which one can see in the `FullForm`:

```
Floor[Mod[H, p1*p2*p3]/(p1*p2*p3)] // FullForm
(*
  Floor[Times[Power[p1, -1], Power[p2, -1], Power[p3, -1],  Mod[H, Times[p1, p2, p3]]]]
*)
```

So to match the denominator with the argument of `Mod` takes something like this:

```
Floor[Mod[H, p1*p2*p3]/(p1*p2*p3)] /. {Floor[
    Mod[H, x_] * y__ /; 1/Times[y] === x] -> 0}
(*  0  *)
```